# Can Jquery Text Editor read and save in rtf format

Tags: rtf

Can Jquery Text Editor read/display and save in rtf format instead of html.

Basically the data that I receive is in HTML, formatted as needed with bold italic and other styling tags, which I want it to be display in an textarea tag and then allow the user to make futher changes to the content and sytling and when I read back / save back the data to the server it should go back in RTF format.

Any help is appreciated.